# How to add an element over the border and have it maintain the position when resizing the window?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to web development and I'm having a hard time with CSS positioning.

I'm trying to make a div separator that looks like an axis: https://ibb.co/pfv8wcm

After resizing the window, the triangles I've added over the border lose their position: https://ibb.co/fS8707P

Code demo: https://liveweave.com/V4lTxA

How can I make it so the triangles maintain the same position on all viewports?

Comment: HI Alem, I would recommend you to use <hr> tag as a separator.

Comment: The code example shared here: https://liveweave.com/V4lTxA is not related to the screenshots, please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding "position-relative" to the container.

```
<div class="container-fluid info-div position-relative">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="box"></div>
      </div>
      <p class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-9">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing         elit. Dolorem odio porro
        obcaecati id ad illo
        accusantium maxime, corrupti deleniti doloremque.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Then you need to modify the bottom arrow css from right:0% to left: 100%

```
.info-div:before {
    bottom: -13px;
    left: 100%;
    border-top: 11px solid transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid black;
    border-bottom: 11px solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

And the top arrow:

```
.info-div:after {
    top: -16px;
    left: -13px;
    border-left: 11px solid transparent;
    border-right: 11px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid black;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `right:0` use `left:100%` which will make the arrow anchored to the outer right edge no matter what, same for top/bottom

```css
body {
  padding: 40px;
}

.box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: darkgray;
}

.outer-div {
  position: relative;
}

.info-div {
  width: 50%;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
  margin: 50px;
}

.info-div:before {
  bottom: -9px;
  left: 100%;
  border-top: 11px solid transparent;
  border-left: 20px solid black;
  border-bottom: 11px solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.info-div:after {
  bottom: 100%;
  left: -9px;
  border-left: 11px solid transparent;
  border-right: 11px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid black;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="outer-div">
  <div class="container-fluid info-div">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="box"></div>
      </div>
      <p class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-9">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Dolorem odio porro obcaecati id ad illo accusantium maxime, corrupti deleniti doloremque.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```